# How to get On Focus CWindow handle?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is there any way to get the handle to the control that has focus?
I am looking for a way to get the ID of control on focus in my app.

After that it would be easy to get the id with GetDlgCtrlID.

```
CWnd *pwnd = GetWindowOnFocus(); 
int wID = pwnd->GetDlgCtrlID();
```

It's the GetWindowOnFocus part that I am missing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the static [CWnd::GetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9fd0z3x(VS.80).aspx) method.

Comment: GetFocus is giving me back HWND - no idea about how to get control ID from HWND :-)

Comment: You need to call the static CWnd::GetFocus method, which returns a CWnd*, not the Win32 ::GetFocus function, which returns an HWND.